# align first element to left in flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

nav a {
  padding: .4rem;
}

.logo {
  justify-self: start;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="/static/logo.svg" alt="PurelyGigs" /></a>
  <a href="/gigs">Gigs</a>
  <a href="/login">Login</a>
  <a href="/register">Signup</a>
</nav>
```

I'm trying to align the logo only to the left and the other three nav items to the right using flex-box...without having to use a wrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do this would be using CSS Grid. We declare one column, that has a width of `1fr` (fr meaning fraction, more information on this can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-css-grid-layout-fr-unit?utm_medium=content_acq&utm_source=css-tricks&utm_campaign=&utm_content=awareness_bestsellers)), meaning it takes up all the space left in the container. This is where the first element - in this case the logo - is added. The other elements get added using `grid-auto-flow`, which means that elements inside the container that would not fit in the provided columns are inserted in auto generated columns without the previously specified width.

Edit: added links being aligned to the bottom.

```css
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  height: 200px;
}

nav a {
  padding: .4rem;
  align-self: end;
}

.logo {
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="/static/logo.svg" alt="PurelyGigs" /></a>
  <a href="/gigs">Gigs</a>
  <a href="/login">Login</a>
  <a href="/register">Signup</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going on here?

Comment: also is there anyway to make the links be at the bottom? The image for logo is quite taller than the links.

Comment: edited the question to adress your questions :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `margin-left: auto;` for the second link. It also allows for simplification of the rest of your CSS.
If you prefer, you can use a class for the second link.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

nav a {
  padding: .4rem;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
}

/* Added */

nav a:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="/static/logo.svg" alt="PurelyGigs" /></a>
  <a href="/gigs">Gigs</a>
  <a href="/login">Login</a>
  <a href="/register">Signup</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: @chovy margin-right: auto for the logo would be more logical

Comment: Nice done @TemaniAlif too. That's a shortcut!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav a {
  padding: .4rem;
}

.logo {
  justify-self: start;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>
        <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="/static/logo.svg" alt="PurelyGigs" /></a>
    </span>
  <span>
        <a href="/gigs">Gigs</a>
        <a href="/login">Login</a>
        <a href="/register">Signup</a>
    </span>
</nav>
```

code